# Uploading images with ckeditor + carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ckeditor, carrierwave

I am trying to add some pictures to the text field of my articles with this gem [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#how-to-generate-models-to-store-uploaded-files).

I first added ckeditor to pretty things up and it works well. After that I added carrierwave as explained on the ckeditor page.

Now everything is working fine except the file upload. As soon as I try to send an image to the server it gives me following error message:

```
Data Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid
```

The files that I tried to upload are getting saved in my `public/upload/tmp` folder though what I find really odd. But still I cant manage to see it in my text field. After uploading the image the text field wont change at all. So I tried to use a url in the first tab of the upload screen that point to the right picture but I cannot figure out how to set up the right url so that I only get a blank image frame with an `X`.

When I try to use an image via a valid link in the second tab I get a message that the url in the first tab is missing again.

So in the end I am really confused on how to load up some images there. Maybe I am just way to stupid but I would really appreciate some help of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You may give `ckeditor-imgur` a try, if you don't plan to manage images by yourself.

The gem help you upload your images to `imgur` in easy way and painless.

https://github.com/yfxie/ckeditor-imgur

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the exact same error, but something similar happened because I did not have imagemagick installed on the server machine - installing it with `brew install imagemagick` fixed it for me (this is for a mac - other environments may require a different command). minimagick requires imagemagick, but imagemagick is not a gem, so it needs to be installed on the machine.